# IDE suggestions for working with big source code files

Tags: c++, android, ide

I am working on an Android application which works with JNI, with already developed C++ and C source codes.

This C/C++ code is really big and I have to study and work on it. Currently I use Eclipse as IDE on Windows XP, which can not properly work with big source code files, like go to declaration, references or search.

So I'm looking for an IDE that covers these requirements:

1. Import and Build JNI layer of and Android project
2. Proper handling of big source code files (some of the files are more than 8k lines)
3. Proper linking, source formatting and code indexing will be very helpful.
4. Running on Windows XP.

If Eclipse is the better option, how can I use it for points 2 and 3?

Comment: `which can not properly work with big source code files, like go to declaration, references or search.` I'm also using Eclipse and apart from being a little bit slower than normal size files, I haven't noticed any actual problems on 10K lines files. Some clarifications on what your problems are?

Comment: Agree with @Yannis. You should not have any problem with a 8k file. Are you on a shared folder or some slow storage ? How old is your computer ? Is the indexer properly turned on ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your computer is powerful enough, eclipse is able to handle a big code base. I have 2-3M lines here with a few files with more than 10k lines and the indexer is working well.

Like you said, Eclipse editor turns off some features for big files above a specific threshold. This "feature degradation" is not always a good thing and can be disabled, or the threshold can be changed if it's too conservative.

Go to *Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Scalability* and tweak.

Currently, I put the threshold on my eclipse at 50k lines for scalability to be turned on. I forgot the default setting, I think it was 5k, hence your problem with files over 8k lines.

Comment: `a few files with more than 50k lines` You are doing something wrong... 50k lines? Seriously? :)

Comment: If those 50k files are not auto-generated, I would think you would have to refactor them a bit.

Comment: @Yannis Correction, my big files are "only" 10k+, I set the 50k threshold myself to prevent scalability to activate and forgot that. Not my code BTW ;)

Answer (score 2):

How big is your software project? **How many millions lines** of source code?

I'm working on GCC, which has (depending on how you neasure) between five and nine millions lines of source code. And I am happy using GNU [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/) (and other Linux utilities, e.g. GNU `make` for building, `etags` ...) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to stay on XP? Win7 is a much better OS. I would suggest the 64-bit version, as it can utilize more than 4GB (it's actually less) of RAM, unlike XP 32-bit. Also, fork out the bucks for a solid-state drive. It will remind you of when you went from dial-up to DSL.

doug